# window.open doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup, window.open

I'm trying to show some info in a pop-up window usig a window.open.. but when I click nothing happens.

This is the function that opens a new window.

```
function goNewWin(sell_code){

// Set height and width
var NewWinHeight=1000;
var NewWinWidth=1000;

// Place the window
var NewWinPutX=10;
var NewWinPutY=10;

//Get what is below onto one line

TheNewWin =window.open("renovations_history.php?sell_code=" + sell_code,
'Renovaciones','fullscreen=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no');

//Get what is above onto one line

TheNewWin.resizeTo(NewWinHeight,NewWinWidth);
TheNewWin.moveTo(NewWinPutX,NewWinPutY);

}
</script>
```

Here's the HTML, with some PHP.

```
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Renovaciones" onClick="goNewWin(<?php echo $row['sell_code']; ?>)">
</form>
```

Nor it works with:

```
<a href="javascript:goNewWin(<?php echo $row['sell_code']; ?>)">Renovaciones</a>
```

It's 2:22 am and I can think straight, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add single quotes to the JavaScript function call:

```
<?php
$sell_code = $row['sell_code'];
?>
<input type="button" value="Renovaciones" onClick="goNewWin('<?php echo $sell_code]; ?>')">
```

Without it, Javascript will consider your `$row['sell_code']` as a javascript keyword.

You need to pass it as a string (function parameter).

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)

Answer (score 0):

if `$row['sell_code']` is a string the you can use

```
$sellCode = $row['sell_code'];

onClick="goNewWin('<?php echo $sellCode; ?>')">
```